# Ubuntu 18.04 with "plugable" docking station and dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, displaylink

I have an Asus UX390 with only a usb-c port. And this docking station: https://plugable.com/products/ud-ultcdl/

If I boot into windows I can connect my 4k monitor to the 4k hdmi port, and a 2560x1440 monitor to the 2k hdmi port.

However under Ubuntu 18.04 even after installing display link drivers the 2k hdmi port seems dead.

I have to choose between Windows and both monitors, or Ubuntu and only one. Which isn't really a choice. But I would like to have both monitors under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with StarTech Dual Dock USB3.0
- just installed the [driver](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1369) (splayLink Linux Driver 5.2.14 )

installed on my Ubuntu 19.04 - it's works great .You're welcome :)